# Is it possible to get a write permission to /Library/ for OSX app with "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write "

Tags: macos, app-store, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

From documentation from apple 
"com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write "
Enables read/write access to the specified files or directories at specified absolute paths." with all sand boxing criteria met.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html

Is this possible with SMJobBless or executing an apple script which gives permission to a Library file path ?

Apple distribution guidelines says OS X application should be sandboxed.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has several answers to it.

- Yes, it is possible to write into /Library/ with a temporay exception
- Applications must be sandboxed when distributed thru Mac App Store
- Otherwise they should but it's not mandatory
- When adding a temporary exception to write into /Library/ you will not pass the review into Mac App Store
- SMJobBless and AppleScript will not help to write into files you don't have permission

There are other ways to accomplish your goals:

- Ask user to get permission to write using NSOpenPanel
- Distribute outside Mac App Store

Finally: What exactly you'd like to write? Probably there are other APIs to change the behaviour.

Comment: It is possible to write file using apple script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880124/apple-script-working-fine-but-with-objective-c-library-not-getting-expected-out?noredirect=1#comment57502723_34880124. Change the folder permission first.

Comment: @iGo of course you can write files using Apple Script as soon as you have permission. You can also ask for permission using Apple Script. How could I improve my answer to get it accepted?